# Field to refresh PowerQuery from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, excel-services

I created excel file with power query connections to SharePoint 365 list. then I upload that excel to SharePoint 356.

The problem happens when I try open this excel file I get the message:

> "failed One or more data connections could not be refreshed in this
>   workbook. Refresh failed on following connections: Query - Budgets"

I tried to do: selected None on Excel Services Authentication settings
also, I have admin permissions on SharePoint o356